# How to cache docker images with GitHub Codespaces devcontainer prebuild?

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, prebuild, github-codespaces

I'm using github codespaces and I have pre-built my devcontainer with feature [kubernetes-helm-minikube](https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/kubernetes-helm-minikube) which contains a minikube pre-installed in the dev container.

My question is, with prebuilding, my devcontainer users still have to download `gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase` image when they run `minikube start` in a newly created codespace. **Is there a way to cache the `minikube start` resources in the prebuild process**? Or **at least cache the gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase image with prebuild**?

Could anyone point out the right way to do that? Greatly appreciate any suggestions.

What I've tried:

- I've read docs in: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/prebuilding-your-codespaces/configuring-prebuilds and https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#_lifecycle-scripts
- I tried run `minikube start` on container create:

```
"onCreateCommand": [
        "nohup bash -c 'minikube start &' > minikube.log 2>&1"
    ]
```

and [the prebuild workflow](https://github.com/AmyGroup-inc/konfig/actions/runs/3574409504) failed with error `$ nohup bash -c 'minikube start &' > minikube.log 2>&1 OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "nohup bash -c 'minikube start &' > minikube.log 2>&1": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

- I tried run `docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.36` on container create and similar error occurred: `starting container process caused: exec: "docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.36": stat docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.36: no such file or directory: unknown`
- I tried run `minikube start` with `postCreateCommand` and the result made it clear that the `postCreateCommand` is only executed after the dev container has been assigned to a user, not during prebuild (as the prebuild doc states).